# how select between tow number 1 and 3 in faker laravel?

Tags: laravel

#### I do not need 2 .I want just 1 or 3 in user_id because it is foreign key and have just 1 and 3 number

```
'user_id' => rand(1,3)->not(2),
        'resnumber' => rand(1000000,5000000),
        'price' => rand(500000,1000000),
        'payment' => rand(0,1),
        'created_at' =>$faker->dateTimeBetween('-7 months','now')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use randomElement()

```
'user_id' => $faker->randomElement([1, 3]),
```

https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase

Answer (score 0):

You can use also numberBetween()

`'user_id' => $faker->numberBetween(0,3)`